# Using older SignalR client on Windows 8.1 Metro Style app

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, windows-8.1

I have a SignalR host, running SignalR 1.1.3.
I've created windows forms client for it successfully using SignalR.Net.Client, and now I would like to create a Windows 8.1 client too.

I've created new universal app project (it creates app both for desktop and windows phone) and using NuGet package manager console I've installed `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client -Version 1.1.3` The command completed successfully, so I started writing code, but there is still error in the line:

```
var _hubConnection = new HubConnection(url);

The type or namespace name 'HubConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

After inspecting my References, I've found out, that there is no `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client` reference.

What I've did wrong and is there any way to use SignalR 1.x on Windows 8.1 application?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have no idea of SignalR host ,

but  when i installed the same  package the way you mentioned it works perfectly for me :-

```
var _hubConnection = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubConnection("www.yahoo.com");
```

It gave me no reference error you mentioned.

Comment: It works perfectly for WinForms application, but does not for Windows 8.1 app. I'll try to reinstall SignalR, maybe it will help.